# Long running delayed_job jobs stay locked after a restart on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, delayed-job

When a Heroku worker is restarted (either on command or as the result of a deploy), Heroku sends `SIGTERM` to the worker process. In the case of `delayed_job`, the `SIGTERM` [signal is caught](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/worker.rb#L125) and then the worker stops executing after the current job (if any) has stopped.

If the worker takes to long to finish, then Heroku will send `SIGKILL`. In the case of `delayed_job`, this leaves a locked job in the database that won't get picked up by another worker.

I'd like to ensure that jobs eventually finish (unless there's an error). Given that, what's the best way to approach this?

I see two options. But I'd like to get other input:

1. Modify `delayed_job` to stop working on the current job (and release the lock) when it receives a `SIGTERM`.
2. Figure out a (programmatic) way to detect orphaned locked jobs and then unlock them.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TLDR:**

Put this at the top of your job method:

```
begin
  term_now = false
  old_term_handler = trap 'TERM' do
    term_now = true
    old_term_handler.call
  end
```

**AND**

Make sure this is called at least once every ten seconds:

```
  if term_now
    puts 'told to terminate'
    return true
  end
```

**AND**

At the end of your method, put this:

```
ensure
  trap 'TERM', old_term_handler
end
```

---

**Explanation:**

I was having the same problem and came upon [this Heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ps#graceful-shutdown-with-sigterm).

The job contained an outer loop, so I followed the article and added a `trap('TERM')` and `exit`. However `delayed_job`  picks that up as `failed with SystemExit` and marks the task as failed.

With the `SIGTERM` now trapped by our `trap` [the worker's handler isn't called](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/worker.rb#L125) and instead it immediately restarts the job and then gets `SIGKILL` a few seconds later. Back to square one.

I tried a few alternatives to `exit`:

- A `return true` marks the job as successful (and removes it from the queue), but suffers from the same problem if there's another job waiting in the queue.
- Calling `exit!` will successfully exit the job and the worker, *but* it doesn't allow the worker to remove the job from the queue, so you still have the 'orphaned locked jobs' problem.

My final solution was the one given at at the top of my answer, it comprises of three parts:

1. Before we start the potentially long job we add a new interrupt handler for `'TERM'` by doing a `trap` (as described in the Heroku article), and we use it to set `term_now = true`.

   **But** we must also grab the `old_term_handler` which the [delayed job worker code](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/worker.rb#L125) set (which is returned by `trap`) **and** remember to `call` it.
2. We still must ensure that we return control to `Delayed:Job:Worker` with sufficient time for it to clean up and shutdown, so we should check `term_now` at least (just under) every ten seconds and `return` if it is `true`.

   You can either `return true` or `return false` depending on whether you want the job to be considered successful or not.
3. Finally it is **vital** to remember to remove your handler and install back the `Delayed:Job:Worker` one when you have finished. If you fail to do this you will keep a dangling reference to the one we added, which can result in a memory leak if you add another one on top of that (for example, when the worker starts this job again).

Comment: @M.ScottFord I have updated the answer, be warned that my previous one would result in a memory leak.

Answer (score 33):

### Abort Job Cleanly on SIGTERM

A much better solution is now built into delayed_job. Use this setting to throw an exception on TERM signals by adding this in your initializer:

```
Delayed::Worker.raise_signal_exceptions = :term
```

With that setting, the job will properly clean up and exit prior to heroku issuing a final KILL signal intended for non-cooperating processes:

> You may need to raise exceptions on SIGTERM signals, Delayed::Worker.raise_signal_exceptions = :term will cause the worker to raise a SignalException causing the running job to abort and be unlocked, which makes the job available to other workers. The default for this option is false.

Possible values for `raise_signal_exceptions` are:

- `false` - No exceptions will be raised **(Default)**
- `:term` - Will only raise an exception on TERM signals but INT will wait for the current job to finish.
- `true` - Will raise an exception on TERM and INT

**Available since Version 3.0.5.**

See [this commit](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/commit/90579c3047099b6a58595d4025ab0f4b7f0aa67a) where it was introduced.

Comment: Thanks for posting. I'll have to check this out.

Comment: How does this deal with issues where a Mailer is communicating to an SMTP server, has completely sent the request and the server has received it, then a `SignalException` is raised before Ruby can close the connection and wrap up the response? It seems like you would then be running the job again. It seems like extra emphasis would have to be put on making jobs 100% atomic.

Comment: It's not really possible to make that sort of distributed systems communication "atomic" without significant re-engineering of both systems. I'd put that in the category of "shit happens." Sometimes multiple mails will be sent. This solution is probably the best that can be done.

Comment: Question: do we have to check or handle this exception in our Job or will the job "fail" and be left unlocked all from this single config line?

Comment: where the mail sending api doesn't provide idempotency (like Stripe does when you add a request ID) you can fake it yourself by [attaching data to messages](https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#attaching-data-to-messages), namely the id of your job that sends the mail (and some namespace/prefix, or a uuid saved in the job), then use the mail service's API to search for mail sent with id that id before re-sending. Assuming 1 worker does the job at a time (with a lock or lease) it should ensure exactly-once sending, unless the api search might miss recently sent messages?

Comment: @maletor Keep in mind that this is rather the dirty solution unless your jobs run for more than 30 seconds. `By default, Signals INT and TERM set @exit, and the worker exits upon completion of the current job.` See: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/v4.1.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb#L55 If you need atomic jobs 1, they shouldn't run long 2, Heroku is simply not the right choice because of this limitation.

Comment: This is not a good solution if you have various short jobs, since you have to deal with the exception in each one of them, when it's better just to wait for the job to finish itself. Unfortunately it looks like you cannot set `raise_signal_exceptions` in a case by case basis, so this solution turned to be unusable for our case.

Answer (score 5):

New to the site, so can't comment on Dave's post, and need to add a new answer.

The issue I have with Dave's approach is that my tasks are long (minutes up to 8 hours), and are not repetitive at all. I can't "ensure to call" every 10 seconds.
Also, I have tried Dave's answer, and the job is always removed from the queue, regardless of what I return -- true or false. I am unclear as to how to keep the job on the queue.

See this [this pull request](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/pull/285). I think this may work for me. Please feel free to comment on it and support the pull request.

I am currently experimenting with a trap then rescue the exit signal... No luck so far.

Comment: This doesn't look like it answers his question. This should either be reposted as a comment or its own question.

Comment: I didn't realize you can't comment unless you have a certain amount of rep, that's annoying, so I understand why you've posted as an answer. That said, I don't know how I didn't find that pull request. I suggest you reword your answer to be, "see this pull request" because I believe it does constitute an answer to the question. I'm also going to post on that pull req now.

Comment: Here's my thoughts on that pull request: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/pull/285#issuecomment-9352052

Answer (score 4):

That is what `max_run_time` is for: after `max_run_time` has elapsed from the time the job was locked, other processes will be able to acquire the lock.

See [this discussion from google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/delayed_job/nGCKoxzdgTY)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up having to do this in a few places, so I created a module that I stick in lib/, and then run ExitOnTermSignal.execute { long_running_task } from inside my delayed job's perform block.

```
# Exits whatever is currently running when a SIGTERM is received. Needed since
# Delayed::Job traps TERM, so it does not clean up a job properly if the
# process receives a SIGTERM then SIGKILL, as happens on Heroku.
module ExitOnTermSignal
  def self.execute(&block)
    original_term_handler = Signal.trap 'TERM' do
      original_term_handler.call
      # Easiest way to kill job immediately and having DJ mark it as failed:
      exit
    end

    begin
      yield
    ensure
      Signal.trap 'TERM', original_term_handler
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: delayed_job 3.0.5 now supports an option to raise an exception on TERM signal: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/commit/90579c3047099b6a58595d4025ab0f4b7f0aa67a

Answer (score 1):

I use a state machine to track the progress of jobs, and make the process idempotent so I can call perform on a given job/object multiple times and be confident it won't re-apply a destructive action. Then update the rake task/delayed_job to release the log on TERM.

When the process restarts it will continue as intended.