What happens to jobs that are executing when a delayed_job process is killed? What if the server is decommissioned?
Say you have a server that gets decommissioned while a job is running. The job never finishes but it stays locked. Will it be stuck forever? Is there any way to rectify this?

Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16811844/1978251.

This is helpful yes.
